# SQL Error adding constraint to table, ORA-01652 - unable to extend temp segment

Tags: sql, oracle, large-data-volumes

I've got this table with millions of rows that I loaded via the `append` hint.

Now I go to turn the constraints back on, I get the following:

2012-03-23 01:08:53,065 ERROR [SQL] [main]: `Error in executing SQL`:

```
alter table summarydata add constraint table_pk primary key (a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-30032: the suspended (resumable) statement has timed out
    ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace MY_TEMP_TABLESPACE`

Are there any best practices to avoid this? I'm adding some more datafiles, but why would this even be a problem?

Comment: Because is a heavy query, it needs to go through every row and see if exists any duplicates on those columns to create the constraint, of course it will be slow. It might be a better option to create an empty table with this constraint and then insert the data from the existing table

Comment: Hmm, after 8 insert into select froms that take about 10 minutes each,  will this take another 80 minutes to insert into the new table? Won't this just use up all of my undo or redo space and crash then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to the *temporay* tablespace, not the data tablespace that holds the table and/or the primary key. You need to increase the size of the `MY_TEMP_TABLESPACE` so it has enough space to do the comparison, as @Lamak indicated.

If you don't know bow much space it wil need the you can turn `AUTOEXTEND` on as @DCookie said, and if it already on (for the temp, not data, tablespace!) then check the `MAXSIZE` setting and increase if necessary. On some platforms the maximum size of a datafile (or for a temp tablespace, hopefully a tempfile) is constrainted so you may need to add additional tempfiles.

If this is a one-off task and you don't want temp to stay big you can shrink it afterwards, but you also have the option to: create a new, large temporary tablespace; modify the user so it uses that instead; build the constraint; modify the user back to the original temp area; drop the new, large temp tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't turn [AUTOEXTEND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3002.htm#i2154658) on for the tablespace?

Comment: It's on, I /believe/ the problem is caused when all of my datafiles get used up and it can't free the first one up fast enough to continue.

Comment: @JBristow - it sounds like you're confusing the behaviour of datafiles and redo logs. Datafiles (or in this case tempfiles) don't get freed up; I think you're referring to redo log rotation outpacing archiving, which can be an issue, but not with this symptom.